# Gear down shift issue in Honda CBR 150R

Tags: honda, motorcycle, gears, cbr250r

I'm having Honda CBR 150R, which is two years old now. I'm facing an issue of gear shifting since the day I bought this bike.

I've mentioned this issue to various mechanics and service centers, but they are unable to fix this. Following is the description:

1. I start my bike, and once in motion, I start shifting the **GEAR UP**. **Gear shifting works fine** in this case.
2. Now once I'm in higher gear (3, 4 or 5) and I try to shift the **Gear DOWN** with clutch fully engaged, I'm unable to shift down. In this case, I have to release the clutch just a little bit and then only the gear respondes to down shift.

Comment: If I'm understanding you, the down shift will only work with the clutch slightly engaged?

Comment: Yes. Precisely speaking, the down shift will only work with clutch around 3/4 engaged. I however already tried to adjust clutch play by tuning the clutch play adjustment screw, but it wasn't very helpful.

Comment: Gear to speed ratio is very important. consider your are going 60 km per hour speed with 5th gear, if you applied break speed will reduced simultaneously you have to reduced the gear. If you reduce the gear from five to four at 20 km per hour, then it will not work properly.

Answer (score 1):

Actually THIS is how gear shifting works.
In order to make the smoothest possible gear change, remember you have to match two rotational speeds on two gears and also momentarily remove torque from the previous selected gear gears, so they can disengage from each other.
With the clutch fully ENGAGED shifting down might be prevented due to high torque already been applied on the originally selected gears.
Another way to change gears without even touching the clutch lever is using your motor RPM to match the speed of your motorcycle-wheel.

Comment: ...or slightly close your throttle so torque is dropped in between these gears and they can disengage

Answer (score 0):

Here are few things you can do,

1. Check if the issue persist while riding your bike in Half Clutch(I dont recommend half clutch - Just for troubleshooting)
2. Try to rev match when you down shift.
3. Did you drop your Bike, try changing your gear lever.
4. check if you are using Manufacturer recommended oil grades